# mysql time to date conversion fetches null value

Tags: mysql

The below mentioned query is returning null but my inner query is fetching values like
[image: shown here]

```
SELECT CONCAT(
FLOOR(HOUR(time_milis) / 24), ' ',
MOD(HOUR(time_milis), 24), ':',
MINUTE(time_milis),':',
SECOND(time_milis)) 
FROM (
  SELECT SUM(TIMEDIFF(logout_timestamp,login_timestamp)) AS time_milis FROM t_access_log WHERE logout_timestamp!='0000-00-00 00:00:00' GROUP BY login_id
)se
```

what am i missing here

Comment: [HOUR()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_hour) works on time not on integer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `time_milis` are all seconds, but [`hour`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_hour) need a `time` like `'10:05:03'`, you can just use [`sec_to_time`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_sec-to-time). Like this:

```
SELECT concat(hour(sec_to_time(time_milis)), ' ', sec_to_time(time_milis))
FROM (
  SELECT SUM(TIMEDIFF(logout_timestamp,login_timestamp)) AS time_milis FROM t_access_log WHERE logout_timestamp!='0000-00-00 00:00:00' GROUP BY login_id
)se
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not using [DATE_FORMAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) for this? So my guess would be something like:

```
SELECT login_id , 
    DATE_FORMAT(
    SUM(
        TIMEDIFF(
            logout_timestamp,login_timestamp)
        )
    ) as some_time
FROM t_access_log
WHERE logout_timestamp!='0000-00-00 00:00:00'
GROUP BY login_id;
```